# Founded iPhone. need help!

Tags: ios, jailbreak, security, activation-lock

A friend of mine found a iPhone 5 and it was on lost mode, then he restored the phone through iTunes. Does Find My iPhone still works, and how do you bypass the activation lock? Should he jailbreak it? I think he should return it to the owner but he wants to sell it.

Comment: If he takes it to an Apple store or a carrier store they should be able to track down the owner using the devices UUID or the phone number.  The owner can also have their phone company disable the sim card.

Did he or did he not succeed in restoring the iPhone 5 to factory settings?  Based on http://help.apple.com/icloud/#/mmb2460cabcf, he should not have been able to erase the phone unless it was still on iOS 6.

Comment: he wants to get in to the phone but he cant because of activation lock? how should he do it

Comment: One question per question is best. Asking what people should do seems pretty arbitrary and subjective and focusing on how to bypass activation lock is already covered, it's not clear to me there's a question here to host...

Comment: _Sigh_, I suppose I should have known better than not to have expected an SE question to make me lose a little more faith in humanity.

Comment: I suppose you should have returned the phone..

Comment: I agree @bmike.  I tried my best to give the facts on the matter but also state my opinion of trying instead to return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he restored the phone to factory settings then they can not track the phone using Find My iPhone.  He will not be able to get past the activation lock, and that is on purpose to reduce a thief's incentive to steal it.   The only possible way would be to take it to Apple and claim he forgot the Apple ID he used on it, but then if (and I hope they would) check the device ID against their sale records they will find it does not belong to him and they will contact the original owner. Really though you should explain to him that its best to get it returned to the owner. There may be a reward if money is what he wants